# How manage resources childs when using resourceRender?

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm using fullcalendar in react and all works fine until I start using the resourceRender prop and the child resources are displaying not as a part of the resource parent expansion anymore. 
How show the child of a resource as to how the default designs?

This is how my resources looks like

```
export const resources = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Conversación estaciones",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Renovaciones Las Americas",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Remuneración II",
    children: [
      { id: "d1", show: true, title: "Room D1" },
      { id: "d2", show: false, title: "Room D2" }
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "Actividades cotidianas",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: "Actividades rudimentarias ",
  }
];
```

And this is how the children resources render in the calendar

[this is how the children resources render in the calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2ZNb.png)

Comment: "until I start using the resourceRender"...ok so how did you use it exactly? If you created a problem by using that callback, you need to show us the code, so we can see what is happening.

Comment: @ADyson here is the example [https://codesandbox.io/s/full-calendar-react-render-event-kwrtn]  I follow is exactly the same code but with my personal design, but the real problem is that when to this example I add to some resource children's then I cant expand/hide them if I use resourceRender. How can I interact with the function to show the children's for some resource ?

Comment: You need to avoid overwriting the entire HTML of the resource. If you inspect the HTML of a resource (before you apply resourceRender to it), you'll see it would have HTML with this structure: `<td class="fc-widget-content" rowspan="1"><div style="height: 32px;"><div class="fc-cell-content"><span class="fc-expander-space fc-expander"><span class="fc-icon fc-icon-minus-square"></span></span><span class="fc-cell-text">Auditorium A</span></div></div></td>`. Basically you want to avoid overwriting anything except the `fc-cell-text` area. You need to target that part of the HTML specifically.

Comment: Now I'm not a React developer so I can't tell you how you do that in React-specific code, exactly. But in regular JavaScript you'd do something like in this demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/XWmVKyz?editors=1010

Comment: If you overwrite the HTML of the entire resource, then clearly it will remove the expander button, and all the formatting that fullCalendar applies, to make it look like a hierarchy of resources (when really it's just a HTML table). So as I say you need to target the cell text element specifically to replace or update the contents of only that part.